# Java List<Integer>

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
public static List<Integer> gradingStudents(List<Integer> grades) {
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++){
        if(grades.get(i) < 40)
            continue;
        else if(grades.get(i) % 5 < 3)
            grades.get(i) = grades.get(i) + (Math.abs(grades.get(i)%5-5));     
        else
            continue;
    }
    return grades;
}
```

I get an unexpected type error at `else if` part. Why can't I change the element of `grades`, like I wrote in the code, above?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot assign to `grades.get(i)`.

I suggest you simplify your code as follows:

```
public static List<Integer> gradingStudents(List<Integer> grades) {
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++){
        int grade = grades.get(i);
        if (grade >= 40 && grade % 5 < 3) {
            grades.set(i, grade + Math.abs(grade%5-5));   
        }  
    }
    return grades;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to modify the list like how you try to modify a list or dict in python as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary). You have to use the inbuilt method `.set()` or `.get()`. `set` is used to add element by replacing it in the given index, `add` method adds the element to given index by pushing rest of the elements. You can understand more about the `set` and `get` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114564/arraylist-set-add-method-usage-java)

To this particular problem, as @Eran mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65591811/7049529), you can use the `.set()` method.